# How to configure apt to get a custom message?

Tags: debian, apt, configuration

In order to solve the must known error displayed by `apt` command without wasting time to find a solution on net, i need to add a custom message "URL to solve the current problem" to the output of `apt` command.

e,g: let's say i get the following error:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The custom message should be:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Please visit : "www.somewebsite.com/how-to-solve-you-have-held-broken-package?"
```

How to configure `apt` to get a custom message?

Comment: By editing the source, surely?

Comment: @Gilles i need to customize a debian installation , if the user get an error when runing `apt` , he can get an additional information (a link to an answer or a few steps to solve the problem) from the same output command (without wasting time to browse and try somes possibles solutions)